Springboot 3.2.4 migration - Getting IllegalArgumentException with "Neither PathPatterns nor String patterns condition" error
I'm trying to migrate my springboot project from 3.1.9 to 3.2.4 and stuck with below exception stack trace.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7d0c21 testClass = au.com.ApplicationTest, other parameters"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5db6b9cd, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@1be2019a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@1b61baec, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@7dc19a70, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@3bcd05cb, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@3eb58b27], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:63)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity@6acee861 of type class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:148)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospectorRequestTransformer': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$1.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:438)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.setApplicationContext(WebSecurity.java:397)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:65)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Neither PathPatterns nor String patterns condition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Neither PathPatterns nor String patterns condition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:368)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.initHandlerMappings(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.afterPropertiesSet(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither PathPatterns nor String patterns condition
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.<init>(RequestMappingInfo.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.combine(RequestMappingInfo.java:355)
    at au.com.org.claims.config.RequestMappingConfig$CustomWebMvcRegistrations$1.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingConfig.java:44)
    at au.com.org.claims.config.RequestMappingConfig$CustomWebMvcRegistrations$1.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingConfig.java:41)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:298)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:224)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 88 more

May be irrelevant but made sure have the following suggestions applied with no success.
Getting following error while migrating Spring boot version from 2.1.6 to Spring boot 2.4

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
